Cook-Levin theorem, why is $\phi _{cell}$ necessary?
Something I didnt understand from both my university course, Sipser, and looking online, is why $\phi _{cell}$, the formula in the Cook-Levin theorem (defined below) which checks that each cell is well defined (contains exactly one symbol), is necessary.
In page 306 of Sipser's Introduction to the theory of computation third edition (chapter 7, time complexity), it says:

The first thing we must guarantee in order to obtain a correspondence
between an assignment and a tableau is that the assignment turns on
exactly one variable for each cell. Formula $ \phi_{\text{cell}} $
ensures this requirement by expressing it in terms of Boolean
operations:
$ \phi_{\text{cell}} = \bigwedge_{1 \leq i, j \leq nk} \left[ \left(
 \bigvee_{s \in C} x_{i,j,s} \right) \land \left(
 \bigwedge_{\substack{s, t \in C \\ s \neq t}} \neg(x_{i,j,s} \land
 x_{i,j,t}) \right) \right]. $

However, if I presume that we are using TMs, which is a safe assumption given that we are building a tableau for the sake of a polynomial reduction, won't each cell for an assignment be exactly equal to a single cell of a TM, 1 or 0 depending on the assignment being true or false, and therefore each cell contains a single value by definition?
Why is $\phi _{cell}$ needed in the first place? Isn't it redundant?
